# live search with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to implement a live search on my site.

I am using a script somebody has already created. http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/live-mysql-database-search-with-jquery/

I have got the Jquery, css, html working correctly but am having troubles with the php.

I need to change it to contain my database information but everytime I do I recieve an error:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 33

These are the details of my database:

database name: development

table name: links

Columns: id, sitename, siteurl, description, category

This is the php script

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "password";
$dbname = "links";

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die                      ('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname);

if(isset($_GET['query'])) { $query = $_GET['query']; } else { $query = ""; }
if(isset($_GET['type'])) { $type = $_GET['type']; } else { $query = "count"; }

if($type == "count")
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT count(url_id) 
                                FROM urls 
                                WHERE MATCH(url_url, url_title, url_desc)
                                AGAINST('$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
    $total = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $num = $total[0];

    echo $num;

}

if($type == "results")
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT url_url, url_title, url_desc 
                                FROM urls 
                                WHERE MATCH(url_url, url_title, url_desc)
                                AGAINST('$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
    while($array = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

        $url_url = $array['url_url'];
        $url_title = $array['url_title'];
        $url_desc = $array['url_desc'];

        echo "<div class=\"url-holder\"><a href=\"" . $url_url . "\" class=\"url-title\" target=\"_blank\">" . $url_title . "</a>

    <div class=\"url-desc\">" . $url_desc . "</div></div>";

    }

}

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Can anybody help me input this database info correctly? I have tried many times but keep getting an error. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: IT IS CONNECTING TO THE DATABASE WITHOUT AN ERROR. CHECK HERE http://movieo.no-ip.org/

Comment: You have a SQL Injection vulnerability.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 1):

the mysql_query() call is failing an returning false instead of a resource. My bet is that mysql_select_db() is failing. This should show the error:

```
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('Couldn\'t select DB: '.mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare: database name: development to $dbname = "links";

I think you should change it to the right name.

Comment: It is connecting to db without an error but selects the wrong table.I think that causes the problem.

Comment: I agree, you said your database name is "development"? Why are you passing "links" to mysql_db_select()?

Answer (score 0):

As well as changing the $dbname to development, check your two SQL statements. They are selecting from the table `urls` instead of `links`.